# why do we say Hashem hoshia... 3 times in korbanot?

Tags: tefilla, maariv

Why in Korbanot and by Arvit do we say the passuk of Hashem hoshia…, Hashem tzvaot ashrei…, and Hashem tzvaot emanu… three times?

Answer (score 1):

The commentary to the Artscroll siddur states that Arizal recommended these verses be recited three times each after reciting *ketoret*. So I guess there is some kabbalistic reason behind it.

(I realize this doesn’t really explain the three-fold recitation at Arvit.)

Comment: Or why not after the ketores said after ein kelokeinu

Comment: @Dude Those who recite ein kelokeinu during the week (nusach sefard and nusach ashkenaz in Israel) as opposed to shabbat and festivals, do recite these verses then